# Excel 2013 - Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a large data set with five columns:

1. Name of employee
2. Total revenue generated by employee
3. Total pay to employee
4. Net revenue from employee (total revenue - pay to employee) and
5. % margin from employee (net revenue divided by total revenue).

I want to do an analysis which shows the difference in average % margin from three different buckets of employees; employees who got paid $40-60K, $60-$80K and $80-100K.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My solution may not be the classiest, but it works. You add an extra column at the end with =IF(PAY<60k,IF(PAY<80,"60k-80k","80k-100k"),"40k-60k") to determine the three categories of employees. Then you insert a pivot table (or graph) and use this last column as row labels.